# Bootstrap scrollbar moves layout left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I've been trying to solve problem I have with Bootstrap layout for hours.

On my site, on full height pages, like http://devpassion.eu/reference.html there is a scrollbar on the right hand side that is moving whole layout left for 8px. 
On the pages that have no full height, there is no scrollbar, like on this one http://devpassion.eu/kontakt.php there is no scrollbar so layout is moved right for same width.

If you open that two pages in two tabs and try just switching it, youll see what I mean.

Any ideas how to solve this and remove that offset that scrollbar does?

Comment: Always show the scrollbar or account for it when it shows up.  They take up space, so you need to give them some consideration.  You can't really tell a scrollbar not to take up space.

Comment: I tried adding, overflow: scroll to body, HTML css tag, but then, double scrollbar is added on a full height page. 
Also, I have a page where I load fb comments http://devpassion.eu/landing.html 
So when the page is loaded, there is no scrollbar at the very begining as the comments are not loaded, and then they are loaded in second or two, scrollbar showes up and the whole layout again moves. Doesnt look good. 
Thanks for your time